# Concurrency or Performance Benefits of yield return over returning a list

Tags: c#, yield, enumerators

I was wondering if there is any concurrency (now or future), or performance benefit to using yield return over returning a list.  See the following examples

Processing Method

```
void Page_Load()
{
  foreach(var item in GetPostedItems())
    Process(item);
}
```

using yield return

```
IEnumerable<string> GetPostedItems()
{
  yield return Item1.Text;
  yield return Item2.Text;
  yield return Item3.Text; 
}
```

returning a list

```
IEnumerable<string> GetPostedItems()
{
  var list = new List<string>();
  list.Add(Item1.Text);
  list.Add(Item2.Text);
  list.Add(Item3.Text);
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Would be fun to debug an iterator block (`yield`) that's lazily initialized (`Lazy<T>`) and asynchronosly (`async`) executed :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the `yield return` example, the result is evaluated on each call of `IEnumerable.MoveNext` whereas in the list example, all results are evaluated before the `IEnumerable` is returned (note that the `Text` properties may not be evaluated for each result as caching and inlining can occur). Therefore, with `yield return` you should get a small performance enhancement on the first call to the enumerator and then potentially a small performance decrease on each subsequent call to `IEnumerable.MoveNext` as the property is evaluated.

One of the great things about `yield return` is that you can return infinite sequences, random sequences, and all sorts of other novel enumerations that would either be extremely inefficient or impossible to do with the model of creating a list first.

To put it simply, returning an instance of `List` requires that all elements in the list are evaluated prior to returning the `IEnumerable`, whereas using `yield return` allows each element to be calculated as it is required by the consumer of the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: So for small lists say under 20 items would you recommend returning just a list.

Comment: It would depend what the elements of the list were and how much effort it took to evaluate each value.  If each element in the list involved opening a 500MB file, then I'd go for the yield return approachs, if it were just a simple calculation, the list would probably be better.

Comment: Yield return can be really useful when you want to traverse the file system.

Comment: @bricklayer137: Only in .NET 4 though, thanks to it's enumerated support. Prior to that, the calls to the file system weren't streaming calls.