# How do I return an empty row when using "yield"?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below code that uses yield to build a collection:

```
public IEnumerable<Comment> GetComments(
    IEnumerable<ContentItem> commentContentItems)
{

    foreach (var commentContentItem in commentContentItems)
    {
        var Comment = new Comment
            {
                CommentCreatedByName = commentContentItem.InitiatorName,
                CommentCreatedByID = commentContentItem.CreatedByID,
                ContentItemID = commentContentItem.ContentItemID,
                CommentDate = commentContentItem.CreatedDate
            };

        yield return Comment;
    }
}
```

I want to start checking if an item is deleted and, if so, yield in such a way as it won't add the deleted item to the collection.

I know I could use linq to reduce the set like this:

```
foreach (var commentContentItem in commentContentItems.Where(x => !x.Deleted))
```

But for arguments sake; how would you do this using yield for, let's say, [situations where yield is more performant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294061/concurrency-or-performance-benefits-of-yield-return-over-returning-a-list)?

eg:

```
if (commentContentItem.Deleted)
{
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: You can put `continue` in your `if`

Comment: as other answers and comments, why would you want to return null? if you do not want that result do not return it.

Comment: You don't need the `if (!commentContentItems.Any())` check. All it does is make your method enumerate `commentContentItems` two time. If `commentContentItems` has no items, the `foreach`-loop won't already do anything...

Comment: Good point @DominicKexel; I've removed it from the sample code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do I get right that you just do not want deleted items in your result?
Then just don't `yield return` in that case!

```
if (!commentContentItem.Deleted)
    yield return Comment;
```

Comment: That's right, so if you don't use the yield keyword, it will pass through to the next item?

Comment: Absolutely! That's the beauty of C#'s `yield` syntax: Execution flows as usual until a `yield ...` statement is hit. No `yield return` means no item is wired to the result enumeration.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to use `Select` here, it's simpler

```
public IEnumerable<Comment> GetComments(
    IEnumerable<ContentItem> commentContentItems)
{
    return commentContentItems.Where(x=>!x.IsDeleted).Select(x=>new new Comment
            {
                CommentCreatedByName = x.InitiatorName,
                CommentCreatedByID = x.CreatedByID,
                ContentItemID = x.ContentItemID,
                CommentDate = x.CreatedDate
            });
}
```

it will work the same and look cleaner. It will do the job and return IEnumerable not containing deleted items.

That is a [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem I think that improving solution is better idea.

Comment: I agree; select does look much cleaner.  This was more a general wondering if you did decide to use yield for, lets say, more complex loops that deal with more than object mapping.